# Spring Cloud Config server is not working after integrating spring security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-config-server

Currently we are shifting our project configurations into github using spring cloud config server. After introducing spring security into our cloud config server, I can not make a call into `/{app}/{profile}/{tag}` url. Our config server have a controller with some endpoints in it. Those endpoints are secure and working fine. But the default endpoint to fetch `configs/files` from github is not working.

I am using `keycloak` & `OAuth2` as idm.

What am I missing here? Any additional configurations in **configure(HttpSecurity http)**? Please help guys..

Advance Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your `cloud-config` uri and credentials configurations you are using to look for from `config-clients`